# VBA DateAdd Outputs Wrong Format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add one month to a date, formatted like 11/30/2018, using the DateAdd fucntion, but no matter what date is input, the output is 12:00:00AM

The ranges for oneCell and twoCell are both in Date formatting in the excel worksheet

```
 For Each aWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(aWorksheet.Name, 1) = "#" Then
        siteNum = Trim(Right(Left(aWorksheet.Name, 5), 4))

        Set oneCell = aWorksheet.Range("C:C").Find("2018")
        Set twoCell = aWorksheet.Range("D:D").Find("2018")

        If oneCell.Row > twoCell.Row Then
            Set oneCell = oneCell.Offset(-1, 0)
        End If

        Do While oneCell.Value <> ""

            billMonthDate = GetBillMonth(oneCell.Value, twoCell.Value)
```

Then the function that is called:

```
Public Function GetBillMonth(ByVal startDate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date) As Date
Dim billMonth As Date
Dim startMonthDays As Integer
Dim endMonthDays As Integer

If DateDiff("m", startDate, endDate) > 1 Then
    billMonth = DateTime.DateAdd("m", 1, startDate)

Else
    startMonthDays = DateDiff("d", startDate, DateSerial(Year(startDate), Month(startDate) + 1, -1))
    endMonthDays = Day(endDate)

    If startMonthDays > endMonthDays Then
        billMonth = oneCellDate
    ElseIf startMonthDays < endMonthDays Then
        billMonth = endDate
    Else
        'fuck me
    End If
End If

GetBillMonth = billMonth

End Function
```

Edit:
The start date is coming from a spreadsheet I'm analyzing. The macro loops through and looks at lots of dates, so I can't just put the date in serially to solve this problem. I just need dateadd to work

Comment: FYI: Using this `?DateTime.DateAdd("m", 1, #11/30/2018#)` in the immediate window results in `12/30/2018`. I think you'll need to add more info to the question.

Comment: If you're seeing `12:00:00AM` - I assume this is in a cell? If so, then that's just down to the formatting of the cell showing the time element of the answer, not the date. Try formatting the cell to `Date`.

Comment: It's not in a cell, it's a date being passed back to the sub via the billMonth variable

Comment: Replace `billMonth = Format(DateTime.DateAdd("m", 1, startDate), "Short Date")` with `billMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, startDate)` It cannot work with `Format` because `Format` returns a string and not a date. Make sure your destination cell is set to the right number format.

Comment: That didn't work either :/ Still getting 12:00:00AM no matter what the startDate is

Comment: Maybe you are hitting this line: `billMonth = oneCellDate` since `oneCellDate` isn't declared, it would give you a 0 date.

Comment: If you are getting `12:00:00AM` then your number format is definitely not correct. Fix the number format of that cell to date eg `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: Rory - you're right that oneCellDate is a mistake. I've changed it to startDate. However the problem is still in the line with the DateAdd function

Comment: @PattiHepler Again, change it to `billMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, startDate)` because using `Format` is definitly wrong (and cannot work). And make sure your cell is formatted as date `"MM/dd/yyyy"`. • If it does not help please show the relevant code part where you write the date into the cell.

Comment: PEH - The cells that I am working with are formatted exactly as you said. I cant figure out why the function wouldn't work with them

Comment: @PEH -  I already took out the format part, and it still returns 12:00:00AM. The relevant code is there in the first block. It sets the ranges accordingly, and then passes their values to the GetBillMonth function. I'm not writing the billMonthDate into the cell. It gets passed back to the first sub for more logic

Comment: We need to see the code after `billMonthDate = GetBillMonth(oneCell.Value, twoCell.Value)` until `billMonthDate` is written into the cell. `billMonthDate` contains the correct date you can check this by using `debug.print billMonthDate` right after that line (just check it). So it must be modified by the following code that we don't see or your destination cell is not formatted correctly.

Comment: Nope. It comes out as 12:00:00AM. Right after the billMonth = DateTime.DateAdd("m", 1, startDate) line. Again, it doesn't get posted in the cell. I have added my workaround solution below.

Comment: There is something wrong then. Please add right before this line `Debug.Print CDbl(startDate)` and right after this line `Debug.Print CDbl(billMonth)` and tell which values you got in your immediate window. If you say *"It comes out as 12:00:00AM."* please tell how did you notice? How did you output it if not in a cell? Probably the error is there. Your code does not show how you output `billMonthDate`

Answer (score 0):

Always use real date values, don't use strings that look like dates.

```
Sub AddOneMonth()  
    Dim StartDate As Date
    StartDate = DateSerial(2018, 11, 30)

    Dim BillMonth As Date
    BillMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate)

    Debug.Print BillMonth   '2018-12-30  
End Sub
```

If working with cells …

```
Sub AddOneMonth()  
    Dim StartDate As Date
    StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    Dim BillMonth As Date
    BillMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = BillMonth
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: startDate is a date variable. It's not a string. I need it to be dynamic since I can't input the date I want every time

Comment: @PattiHepler Then just read the date from your cell like `StartDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`. If that doesn't help you, please edit your original question and show your relevant code or a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround for anyone interested:

```
    If Month(startDate) + 1 > 12 Then
        billMonth = DateSerial(Year(startDate) + 1, 1, 1)
    Else
        billMonth = DateSerial(Year(startDate), Month(startDate) + 1, 1)
    End If
```